# How to properly display the date and time in chat message box

Tags: css

I am developing a chat application. In that chat message box I need to show a message, the user's name, current date and time. I am showing all those things except time and date UI is not looking good.

```css
.userTextDivOp {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.userTextDivOp::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -3px;
  left: -11px;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-top: 11px solid #999;
}

.userTextDivOp::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  left: -6px;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid white;
  clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp .message {
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.userTextDivOp .username {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8e0035;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.userTextDivOp .time {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f60;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="userTextDivOp">
  <span class="username">UserName</span>
  <span class="message">' Testing testing</span>
  <span class="time">04:00 PM 7 Jul 2016</span>
</div>
```

Comment: So why did you tag this question in javascript..... Its about css

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` of `.time` and add `display: block` to it. See [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/cq2ja1uz/1/)

Comment: i think u can use a light gray color for the time and date. it shouldn't be prominent. e.g. `#eee` and a bit smaller `font-size`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.userTextDivOp {
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 4px;
}

.userTextDivOp::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: -3px;
 left: -11px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 11px solid #999;
}

.userTextDivOp::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: 0px;
 left: -6px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 8px solid white;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.userTextDivOp .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #8e0035;
   text-align:left;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.userTextDivOp .time {
 position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
   color: #f60;
}
```

```html
<div class="userTextDivOp" >
  <span class="username">UserName</span>
  <span class="message">' Testing testing</span>
  <span class="time">04:00 PM 7 Jul 2016</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time class to define the span you want to change.

```css
.userTextDivOp {
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-left: 4px;
}

.userTextDivOp::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: -3px;
 left: -11px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 11px solid #999;
}

.userTextDivOp::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 visibility: visible;
 top: 0px;
 left: -6px;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-top: 8px solid white;
 clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp .message {
 word-break: break-all;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.userTextDivOp .username {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #8e0035;
   text-align:left;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.userTextDivOp .time {
  //#You can edit these style settings to edit how the Time and date look
 position: relative;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: pink;
   padding: 0 20px;
   font-family: courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="userTextDivOp" >
  <span class="username">UserName</span>
  <span class="message">' Testing testing</span>
  <span class="time">04:00 PM 7 Jul 2016</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isnpite of using    You can use the  tag with datetime attribute , Time is just an HTML tag. Here's a simple example that represents November 2011:

```
   <time> 2011-11 </time>
```

And The datetime attribute is what makes the time element unique. It represents the date, time, or duration for whatever text you are representing in a machine readable format. That means it is for computers, not humans, so it has very specific formats.

It's probably a bit more common for the human-readable version to be just a textual representation of the datetime:

```
  <time datetime="2011-11">November, 2011</time>

  <time datetime="2013-04-01">April 1st, 2013</time>

  <time datetime="5d 22h 54m 41s">5 days, 22 hours, 54 minutes, and 41    seconds</time>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, One thing You can do, like facebook ; You can make the time visible when someone hovers the chat message.

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cq2ja1uz/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="userTextDivOp" >
    <span class="username">UserName</span>
    <span class="message">' Testing testing</span>
    <span class="time">04:00 PM 7 Jul 2016</span>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

.userTextDivOp {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    background: white;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.userTextDivOp .time {
    position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f60;
  left: 125px;
  top: 0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.userTextDivOp:hover .time {
  visibility:visible;
}

.userTextDivOp::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    top: -3px;
    left: -11px;
    border: 9px solid transparent;
    border-top: 11px solid #999;
}

.userTextDivOp::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0px;
    left: -6px;
    border: 9px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    clear: both;
}

.userTextDivOp .message {
    word-break: break-all;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.userTextDivOp .username {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #8e0035;
    text-align:left;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```